# unable to display data from eloquent relationship with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to display data from an eloquent relationship in my view but I seem to be doing something wrong. Here's my model relationship, controller and view

Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Price

```
class Price extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function product()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('prices')->get();

    return view('home', compact('products'));
}
```

View

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $product->prices->date }}</td>
    <td>{{ ucwords($product->name) }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->prices->cost }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

My view returns the error 
`Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance`
How do i fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hasMany relations you have a Collection as result, so you should have another `foreach` to access each `Price`. Try something like this:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @foreach ($product->prices as $price)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $price->date }}</td>
            <td>{{ ucwords($product->name) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $price->cost }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Wow! Never knew it works like this. Problem solved, thanks.